# What is the `confidence` parameter of `findHomography` in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, homography, ransac

On [the documentation of `findHomography`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.8.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) I see 4 options:

- 0 - a regular method using all the points, i.e., the least squares method
- RANSAC - RANSAC-based robust method
- LMEDS - Least-Median robust method
- RHO - PROSAC-based robust method

What I miss an explanation for the confidence parameter:

```
confidence Confidence level, between 0 and 1.
```

How does it impact each of the methods above? What’s its usage?